# What are some good ASCII art generators?

Tags: software-recommendation, ascii

I have tried **figlet** but it's not much good. Are there any other ASCII editors?
 [image]

Comment: what exactly do u mean by ascii editor? I mean every text editor should be able to edit ascii like gedit because ascii is just an encoding for characters

Comment: I mean softwares like figlet..

Comment: So a generator?

Comment: @Oli yep you are right.

Comment: not related, but i remember there being a tool called aa or maybe bb in the knoppix cd, that made ascii vidoes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[TOIlet](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/toilet) [image: Install TOIlet]

I've seen [**TOIlet**](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/toilet), I think that is what you're looking for.

Comment: In terminal it's oke but when i copy that into my text editor.It is not in the original form.

Comment: I believe you need to use a monospaced font for the ASCII art to render properly, you don't get aligned char positions with a variable font.

Comment: Is it possible to install monospaced font from repositories?

Comment: There are several monospaced fonts installed by default. Some of them have "mono" in their name, so should be easy to find.

Comment: @JanC if is installed by default.Why it's not appearing properly?

Comment: when you copy/paste, you don't include the font info...

Comment: I think, when looking at the TOIlet screenshots, your problem might be different.  It seems like it (sometimes) uses colour and non-default characters, which is probably the problem you see, not the lack of a monospaced font.

Answer (score 26):

[jp2a](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/jp2a) [image: Install jp2a]

Another good program available in the repositories is `jp2a`, and there is some good documentation on it at the [official site](http://csl.sublevel3.org/jp2a/) and on the [Ubuntu manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/jp2a.1.html).

It should be said that the program will convert any jpg, but it is best to use simple, logo or cartoon like pictures as they come out much better. If you need to convert your image to jpg beforehand, just use `imagemagick's` convert utility and run `convert logo.png logo.jpg`.

There is often a need to fiddle with the `jp2a` options to specify the characters used, the size of the ascii, or to invert the representation. Once you get the settings right you can get good results, however, as I display in the screenshot below. The results do, however, depend a lot on the image you have chosen to convert to ascii.

As an example, I have used the following command to do an ascii representation of the Ubuntu logo, which displays on the terminal screen and also saves to file: (This assumes the input `ubuntu-logo.jpg` is in your present working directory)

```
jp2a -i --chars="..00xx@@" ubuntu-logo.jpg | tee ubuntu-logo.txt
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to output this automatically to an image? (i.e. without taking a screenshot)

Comment: @hellocatfood: Yes. `echo -en "hello\nworld" | python3 -c "import sys; from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont; img=Image.new('RGB',(800,600)); draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img); font = ImageFont.truetype('/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeMono.ttf', 20); [draw.text((0, i[0]*20), i[1].rstrip('\n'), (255,255,255), font=font) for i in enumerate(sys.stdin)]; img.save('sample-out.png')" && display sample-out.png`

Answer (score 13):

If you want a talking cow there is `cowsay` [image: Install cowsay]:

```
$ cowsay hello!
 ________
< hello! >
 --------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

Answer (score 4):

There are also many cool online converters. Some of them convert text, and some can process ever images! Look at http://www.text-image.com/convert/ or http://ajaxwidgets.com/Ascii-Art/AsciiArt.aspx

Amongst those that deal with text is http://patorjk.com/software/taag/

Comment: Alright but the problem now is when i copy it to my text editor.It was not in the original form.

Comment: It depends on how did you copy it. Which site did you use? I'll try myself.

Comment: Used this site http://patorjk.com/software/taag/

Comment: Remember to use proper font.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a step further, if you like to learn a new command with ascii art generated cartoon character like shown below.
[image: demo1]
[image: demo2]

You can use `cowsay` utility and put a simple one line to learn new command.

installing cowsay

```
sudo apt-get install cowsay
```

add below line to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file located at `~/` i.e `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` to get an ascii art character

```
cowsay -f $(ls /usr/share/cowsay/cows | shuf -n 1 | cut -d. -f1) $(whatis $(ls /bin) 2>/dev/null | shuf -n 1)
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There is a Java Application [JaVE](http://www.jave.de/) that does what you are looking for.

Another, CLI based project would be [AA-lib](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aalib/).

Comment: Do you know how you'd save the output of aa-lib to an image _without_ taking a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

I love **Linux-logo** ( http://www.deater.net/weave/vmwprod/linux_logo/ ).
Try adding it to the start of any terminal. Try finding the right logo for Ubuntu (-L)...

---

Have fun!

Comment: Lots of fun, but it's not actually and acii art generator

Answer (score 0):

I use **asciio** with my python scripts. How to install:

```
apt-get install asciio
```

[image: Imagem asciio]

Comment: This is an English site.  If you're going to post in spanish, please at least translate your post to English.

Comment: You're right. I will try to translate the next.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 5 year old son who loves [asciiquarium](https://github.com/cmatsuoka/asciiquarium). Asciiquarium is a single perl script, so all you have to do is make sure it's executable and put it somewhere convenient, like `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/local/games`.

**Additional requirements for Ubuntu**

1. Get perl's curses package which is available from apt.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libcurses-perl
   ```
2. Run `cpan` from the shell. Agree to the defaults for everything. To leave cpan, type `quit`
3. Type:

   ```
   sudo cpan Term::Animation
   ```

[image]

Comment: Neither searching [by command name](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=asciiquarium) nor searching [by package name](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=asciiquarium) yielded any results.

Answer (score -3):

Here is a good ascii art generator: http://asciiart.club

```
                                     y#▓▓▓▓▓▄     
                                    #▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓    
                      ¿╓╔###║###M╔  ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓    
                    ╙║║║║║║║║║║║║║░ └▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓┘    
               ╔╠░    ║║║║║║║║║║║║║N, └╙╩╩╙└      
             ╔╠╠╠╠╠,   ╚║║║║║║║║║║║║║║M╔╓╓╓#N,    
           ╓╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠∩   ╙╙      └╙╙║║║║║║║║║║║N   
          #╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╚                ╙║║║║║║║║║║  
         ╔╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╚                    ╙║║║║║║║║║ 
  .╓╔╔╓,  ╙╠╠╠╠╠╠╚                      ╙║║║║║║║║Γ
.║║║║║║║║,  ╠╠╠╠╠                        ║║║║║║║║║
║║║║║║║║║║  ╠╠╠╠░                                 
╚║║║║║║║║╠  ╠╠╠╠░                        ╓»»»»»»»»
 ╙╚║║║║╚╙  #╠╠╠╠╠∩                       ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒
         ╔╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠,                    \▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ 
         `╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠∩                  #▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓Ñ 
           ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠              ╓@▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓╜  
            ╙╠╠╠╠╠╠╚   ┌▓▓₧MmmM₧▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓    
              ╙╠╠╠∩   ╓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▀░      └     
                `    #▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓  ╓∩╠╠╠╠∩╔     
                    "▀▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓  #╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠░    
                          └└└└└└    ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠    
                                     ╚╠╠╠╠╠╠╠     
                                       └╙╙╙
```

It can generate in full color from a variety of character sets, from oldskool/amiga to ascii or extended (even braille!), and generates output in HTML, BBCode, Markdown, and even share an image on [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0AY5.jpg) with one click.

Try it! -=cP

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. If you post answers suggesting tools you have written or are otherwise involved with, please make sure to always state that in the answer. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/help/promotion) for the site rules about promotion.