# How can I print existing ASCII art from a Bash script?

Tags: bash, ascii-art

I've just seen the following ASCII art.

```
          0000_____________0000________0000000000000000__000000000000000000+
        00000000_________00000000______000000000000000__0000000000000000000+
       000____000_______000____000_____000_______0000__00______0+
      000______000_____000______000_____________0000___00______0+
     0000______0000___0000______0000___________0000_____0_____0+
     0000______0000___0000______0000__________0000___________0+
     0000______0000___0000______0000_________000___0000000000+
     0000______0000___0000______0000________0000+
      000______000_____000______000________0000+
       000____000_______000____000_______00000+
        00000000_________00000000_______0000000+
          0000_____________0000________000000007
```

I have a bash script that I would like to print this from. How can I do that?

This is something I might want to redistribute so to keep things simple, I'd prefer if answers didn't require additional things to be installed.

Comment: I don't think anything in the question is unreasonable if you look at it the right way. It's essentially **"How do I print *this* string in Bash?"**. Once you accept that, installing things that only approximate the desired outcome does seem rather silly.

Answer (score 23):

This is the shortest form I was able to produce, that prints exactly that `007` string:

```
base64 -d <<<"H4sIAJM2MVYAA1NQgAEDIIhHBsgCBmgAU8TAQJsL2SgU41AFiDALYRhUF8I0NAEUCbBZUB7MBGRrUXX
g8DC6CagORwkYtDCDcw3IMwDdOBL1IyRRwpBI7cihTlSYkRRNUHcRnUZgXIQGIlOoOQC/4ufk0gIAAA==" | gunzip
```

Comment: Nice should of though of compression :) I guess its possible to compress other things with something like `echo string | gzip -cf | base64`?

Comment: @Wilf Just: `echo string | gzip | base64` and yes the `base64` is just that we have only alphanumeric characters .Btw `gzip` is very effective in compressing text, as you can see.

Comment: this is by far the best solution!

Comment: Note OSX base64 doesn't have the `-d` option, instead you must use `-D`

Comment: For those who don't know how to paste multi-line in terminal. paste it in a file then: `cat your_ascii_art.txt | gzip | base64`

Answer (score 16):

What about just `echo`?:

```
echo -e "              0000_____________0000________0000000000000000__000000000000000000+\n            00000000_________00000000______000000000000000__0000000000000000000+\n           000____000_______000____000_____000_______0000__00______0+\n          000______000_____000______000_____________0000___00______0+\n         0000______0000___0000______0000___________0000_____0_____0+\n         0000______0000___0000______0000__________0000___________0+\n         0000______0000___0000______0000_________000___0000000000+\n         0000______0000___0000______0000________0000+\n          000______000_____000______000________0000+\n           000____000_______000____000_______00000+\n            00000000_________00000000_______0000000+\n              0000_____________0000________000000007;"
```

<sup>Every newline has been replaced with `\n` to shove it all into one line</sup>

[image]

It won't resize to the terminal though etc (unless you check the terminal width and `echo` one that is the right size), and it isn't that short either *(is there a way to repeat characters better?)* but it should work. If you want the colours as well you can use [escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#graphics):

```
echo -e "\033[31m           0000\033[0m_____________0000________0000000000000000__000000000000000000+\n\033[31m         00000000\033[0m_________00000000______000000000000000__0000000000000000000+\n\033[31m        000\033[0m____000_______000____000_____000_______0000__00______0+\n\033[31m       000\033[0m______000_____000______000_____________0000___00______0+\n\033[31m      0000\033[0m______0000___0000______0000___________0000_____0_____0+\n\033[31m      0000\033[0m______0000___0000______0000__________0000___________0+\n\033[31m      0000\033[0m______0000___0000______0000_________000___0000000000+\n\033[31m      0000\033[0m______0000___0000______0000________0000+\n\033[31m       000\033[0m______000_____000______000________0000+\n\033[31m        000\033[0m____000_______000____000_______00000+\n\033[31m         00000000\033[0m_________00000000_______0000000+\n\033[31m           0000\033[0m_____________0000________000000007;"
```

[image]

By the way you may want to consider copyright and boring stuff depending onhow you are using it - e.g. [this version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:007_logo.svg) which is similar seems to still be in copyright.

Comment: The colors in the question were automatically applied by the syntax highlighter.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson - I know, but a) they sort of look quite cool sort and b) its a example of how colours can be used.

Answer (score 15):

Put the characters in a file and `cat` it.

```
cat 007.txt
```

Use a "here document"

```
cat <<EOF
      0000_____________0000________0000000000000000__000000000000000000+
    00000000_________00000000______000000000000000__0000000000000000000+
    . . .
EOF
```

`echo` a string with embedded newlines

```
echo '          0000_____________0000________0000000000000000__000000000000000000+
    00000000_________00000000______000000000000000__0000000000000000000+
    . . .'
```

The advantage of these approaches is that the art is still readable.

Answer (score 12):

Shamefully borrowing ( aka stealing ) [B.Roland's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/16838/295286) , I suggest a package with a colorfull name   . . . toilet ! Which you can get with `sudo apt-get install toilet`  and it works roughly like this:

```
xieerqi:$ toilet 007

  mmmm   mmmm  mmmmmm
 m"  "m m"  "m     #"
 #  m # #  m #    m" 
 #    # #    #   m"  
  #mm#   #mm#   m"
```

It also supports changing fonts ( located in `/usr/share/figlet` )

```
 toilet -f bigascii12  LINUX                                                                                 



 ##         ######   ###   ##  ##    ##  ##    ## 
 ##         ######   ###   ##  ##    ##  :##  ##: 
 ##           ##     ###:  ##  ##    ##   ##  ##  
 ##           ##     ####  ##  ##    ##   :####:  
 ##           ##     ##:#: ##  ##    ##    ####   
 ##           ##     ## ## ##  ##    ##    :##:   
 ##           ##     ## ## ##  ##    ##    :##:   
 ##           ##     ## :#:##  ##    ##    ####   
 ##           ##     ##  ####  ##    ##   :####:  
 ##           ##     ##  :###  ##    ##   ##::##  
 ########   ######   ##   ###  :######:  :##  ##: 
 ########   ######   ##   ###   :####:   ##    ##
```

Comment: thanks =)...I have `toilet` installed and I am using (funny) commands mentioned here http://www.tecmint.com/20-funny-commands-of-linux-or-linux-is-fun-in-terminal/

Comment: @Ravan if I may ask, you specifically want a script that displays only 007 ? Or you want it to be an ascii art generator ?

Comment: either way, but not just 007, please see linked post =)

Comment: I wonder what happens when I do `toilet --flush`... =)

Comment: Did not know about toilet. Is the program able to put the output into an ascii sequence in order that you put the output into scripts where no `toilet` is available?

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 well, without a certain ascii art generator , like `figlet` or `toilet`, you could use for loops in `awk` or `bash` but . . . .that's kind of a lot of work if you don't have time

Comment: @Serg So better copy and paste and insert new lines and stuff?

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355   Sort of . . . I personally would do a vertical text, again with for loops in awk.   But it's not impossible to set up a script with just bunch of `printf` statements

Comment: @Serg Alright... I will remember it for future scripts for other users to get a funny or impressive heading =)

Comment: Is toilet a badly named [figlet](http://www.figlet.org/)?

Comment: @jdv sort of . The [home page](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/toilet) for this project says it's intended to be a replacement  for `figlet`

Answer (score 6):

Install `banner` package and create a bash script

```
sudo apt-get install sysvbanner
```

check below example of command

```
banner 007
```

Comment: thanks =), I have idea about `banner` .I need 007 like in linked post.

Answer (score 6):

Usage

```
cat << "EOF" 
your_ascii_art 
EOF
```

See the below example

```
 cat << "EOF"

      0000_____________0000________0000000000000000__000000000000000000+
    00000000_________00000000______000000000000000__0000000000000000000+
   000____000_______000____000_____000_______0000__00______0+
  000______000_____000______000_____________0000___00______0+
 0000______0000___0000______0000___________0000_____0_____0+
 0000______0000___0000______0000__________0000___________0+
 0000______0000___0000______0000_________000___0000000000+
 0000______0000___0000______0000________0000+
  000______000_____000______000________0000+
   000____000_______000____000_______00000+
    00000000_________00000000_______0000000+
      0000_____________0000________000000007

EOF
```

Given below some ascii art generator sites.

1. http://patorjk.com/software/taag/
2. http://www.network-science.de/ascii/
3. http://www.glassgiant.com/ascii/
4. http://www.kammerl.de/ascii/AsciiSignature.php
5. http://picascii.com/

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of doing this would be to just put the art into a file and then `echo` it. That way it preserves the original representation in the file, so you can identify it easily!

```
echo '         0000_____________0000________0000000000000000__000000000000000000+
        00000000_________00000000______000000000000000__0000000000000000000+   
       000____000_______000____000_____000_______0000__00______0+           
      000______000_____000______000_____________0000___00______0+           
     0000______0000___0000______0000___________0000_____0_____0+            
     0000______0000___0000______0000__________0000___________0+             
     0000______0000___0000______0000_________000___0000000000+              
     0000______0000___0000______0000________0000+                           
      000______000_____000______000________0000+                            
       000____000_______000____000_______00000+                             
        00000000_________00000000_______0000000+                            
          0000_____________0000________000000007'
```

Comment: Essentially identical to part of my answer.